# Web Service is running on local host but showing error on azure cloud

Tags: web-services, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created a web service which will do some long string calculation and will return result in json format .
Also written a demo app to test that web service.

I have tested the web service on my local machine. 
Its working good when I used 64 bit compiler. 
For 32 bit it doesn't work well due to memory constraints.(I am fine with 62 bit compiler)

Issue:
When I tried running my script on azure cloud. Its getting failed for heavy data calculation with error " Response status Code: does not indicate success: 502(Bad Gateway) "

I am unable to find reason for that.

Some Possibilities :

- Do I require to turn any option to 64 bit explicitly for azure cloud.
- By any chance timeout is happening, If yes then how to remove that
- I am working on basic free trial of Microsoft azure version, Does they have some limitation for that.

I am calling the web service through "client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://featuretracking.azurewebsites.net/");"

and local host through "http://localhost:56411/"

I have deployed as web app on azure.

Comment: Free trial has nothing to do with it. But... how about editing your question to show what the general format of your web service call looks like. Does it rely on a specific port? Also: You don't mention *how* you put it into Azure: Web App? VM? Cloud Service?

Comment: @DavidMakogon: did the editing.

Answer (score 0):

There is an offical [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-troubleshoot-http-502-http-503/) for troubleshooting http error 502 & 503, which list some reasons below for the issue and how to troubleshoot.

> - requests taking a long time
> - application using high memory/CPU
> - application crashing due to an exception.

Please check `eventlog.xml` file in the `logFiles` folder via access the kudu tool `https://<your-webapp-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/` to see what happended at the time of error 502.